# How to assign new values to a raster on conditional bases

Tags: qgis-3

I have one condition to apply on my raster where the value range of my raster file is 7.3-37.

Now I want to assign the new values based on the different ranges such as:

- values <= 16 are equal to 0.088
- value range from < 16 <= 24 is equal to 0.012
- value range from < 24 <= 32 is equal to 0.163
- values > 32 are equal to 0

How can I apply this expression in QGIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Processing Toolbox find 'Reclassify by table' and use it. Interface of this toolbox is very clear.